# Where are the community ads?

Tags: support, bug, sidebar

If I understand correctly, the ads with enough upvotes in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/community-promotion-ads-2016) should appear in the sidebar on the main site. However, the ads I see there look like generic stackexchange ads for other communities and Area 51 proposals rather than [our upvoted community ads](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/22419).

I have checked using multiple browsers and devices and both logged in and logged off, but I cannot get the community ads to show.

Does anyone else here have the same problem? Am I doing something wrong or is the community ad system broken?

Answer (score 8):

As of now, I see old (narrow) ads from 2015 on the site. Also, the [statistics page for 2016 ads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/22419) shows very few clicks on them, indicating they are not being shown on the main site.

Someone at SE should flip the switch from "2015" to "2016", and it hasn't happened. [Grace Note commented yesterday](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/community-promotion-ads-2016#comment7370_1779):

> The switch should've been thrown last month. I'll check on it today.

Hopefully, the check will lead to resolution.